# I am trying to enter a list into dataframe new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have saved the output into a list and i want to create a new column and add the values there

I could successfully do it with anaconda but i am now trying it python and IDLE it is not working

```
attendance = []
sleep(5)
for x in df1['Login Time']:
    s1 = str(x)
    s2 = '12:00:00'
    s3 = '3:15:00'
    s4 = '02:00:00'
    FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
    if x <= s4:
        attendance.append('Aussi')
    elif (str(tdelta)) < s3:
        attendance.append('Present')
    else: 
        attendance.append('Check')
df1['Attendance'] = attendance
sleep(5)
df1.to_csv(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')+".csv",index=False)
```

I am getting the error
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: That is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `df1['Attendance'] = attendance`

Try this:

```
attendance = []
sleep(5)
for x in df1['Login Time']:
    s1 = str(x)
    s2 = '12:00:00'
    s3 = '3:15:00'
    s4 = '02:00:00'
    FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
    if x <= s4:
        attendance.append('Aussi')
    elif (str(tdelta)) < s3:
        attendance.append('Present')
    else: 
        attendance.append('Check')
#From Here......................................................
attendance_df = pd.Dataframe(attendance,column=['Title']
df1.loc[attendance_df.index,'Login Time']=attendance_df['Title']
#...............................................................
sleep(5)
df1.to_csv(datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%Y-%m-%d')+".csv",index=False)
```

Hope this works.

Comment: i get an error for invalid syntax for df1['Attendance"]

Comment: invalid syntax - df1

Comment: Try the change above. 'Login time' was changed

Comment: i have uploaded a screenshot for the same

Comment: the last line seems repeated? Sorry, please change 'attendance.index' with 'attendance_df.index'

Comment: deleted the last line that was being repeated, and made the changes but still getting the syntax error for df1.